# making request onion sites without tor

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

I made a simple server at my home hosted by tor. The server contains my personal files and i dont like paying services for hosting websites because hosting on tor is free and hidden. It doesn't matter if i'm not using tor to connect to my onion website because im the owner of it so... yeah. I tried any to search for socks support for net but i found nothing and also i dont like using 3rd party libraries and some have 30 day trial which sucks. BUT....... basically the only barrier i really have is that i cannot connect Socks proxy using NET framework. please help i need guidance... thank you

Comment: So you are trying to subvert the whole point of having Tor?

Answer (score 0):

> I made a simple server at my home hosted by tor. The server contains
>   my personal files and i dont like paying services for hosting websites
>   because hosting on tor is free and hidden. It doesn't matter if i'm
>   not using tor to connect to my onion website because im the owner of
>   it so...

Is this an http, ftp, windows file server?

> I tried any to search for socks support for net but i found nothing
>   and also i dont like using 3rd party libraries and some have 30 day
>   trial which sucks.

I take it that you are attempting to develop and application that can reach your server from inside and outside?

My suggestion:

Don't try to do everything from scratch. Install Apache and MySQL and then install NextCloud/OpenCloud. This will give you everything you need to access your files quickly at home like a NAS. It uses standard webDAV http/https requests.

You can also have apache work with Tor to create an onion service. When you are away from home use Tor Browser to access your files remotely. You can even set up the Nextcloud application to sync via Socks 5 though this might be very slow if you sync large files.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with all this complications if it's for personal use only?
You may simply use remote desktop or VNC.
Less troubles and access from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can easily utilize HTTP proxy from tor: it's been a while as it was added and built-in. For connecting to your server's services you can basically use anything you wish, but if you're about to have a very tunable playground for yourself - here is my advice how to build the things up:

- **VirtualBox** or **ProxMox** as a basement. If you don't need a hardware pass-through like NVidia CUDA running inside a virtual machine - use VirtualBox.
- **OpenVPN** inside **Tor** - the "gateway" VM with just Tor, OpenVPN, easyRSA and a firewall. Debian or FreeBSD - they will consume as small as 1-2Gb RAM if you'll have a middle-relay tor node or even less like 256-512Mb RAM if you have a *ClientOnly* mode for tor. **Important notice**: The only port you need to open on your router is this VM's tor ORPort! Also don't forget about setting the HS per-user access certificate for your remote client connection - it's a **must**
- **Anything else** is located on another virtual machines, all of them do have an internal network that gateway VM provides an access to via OpenVPN hidden service.

That's it! Fast and easy to build, secure and extendable. If you'll be upgrading to your home LAN laboratory(as I did) - just add a physical NIC to your server and your home LAN for your devices will be plugged into that particular card and it will be the replacement for the logical host-only network